# resources.ap_ does not generate when compile my android project

Tags: android

When i run my project its give me below error.

Compile Error: Error generating final archive: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ..\bin\resources.ap_ does not exist.

I tried to clean my project but also it can not generate the resource.ap_ file and my apk file size is 0..

please help me to solve this problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite often problems like this can be solved by deleting the project from your eclipse workspace (NOT deleting the project files) then importing the project back into the workspace. Give it a try...

Comment: hey thanks its work when i restart my eclipse and again import that project

Answer (score 0):

Usually the following steps work:
ADT -> Project -> Clean